# code convertor vb6 to javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, vb6, newline, converters

can any body help to convert this code from VB6 to JavaScript

```
Sub Insert()
Dim j As Long, r As Range
j = InputBox("Enter the number of sizes -1")
Set r = Range("A2")
Do
Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)
If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: you can't. you don't have the cells, range and offsets in plain JS.

Comment: Do you want to execute the JavaScript (you are looking for) inside Excel using MS ScriptControl? Or what is your execution environment?

Comment: This looks like it's for Excel VBA which can't use JScript. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `Range` or `Cell` classes in *VB*, but if you re-implement their behaviour in JavaScript, your code could be converted to the following

```
function VBRange(/* args */) {
    // re-implementation
}
function VBCells(/* args */) {
    // re-implementation
}
function Insert() {
    var j, r;
    j = parseInt(prompt(Enter the number of sizes -1), 10);
    r = VBRange("A2");
    do {
        VBRange(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow().Insert();
        r = VBCells(r.Row + j + 1, 1);
        if (r.Offset(1, 0) === "") {
            break;
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but what i needed is the cell and range functions :),
this code is used in excel to do somthing .

i need the code but in javaScript

Comment: @Hamzawoo maybe take a look at this link, then http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/11/30/introducing-the-javascript-object-model-for-excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx